# Dealing One Card to Each Player Before Dealing a Second Card - Blackjack Game in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, blackjack

I have made the following code in Python. Where deck = deck_of_cards(). My question is how to I fix the second function so that it must deal a first card to each player before dealing a second card. The way it is right now seems to deal two cards to a player before dealing cards to the other players and I don't know how to fix it.

```
import random
def deck_of_cards():
    suits = ['D', 'C', 'H', 'S']
    denominations = ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', 
                     '9', 'T', 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A']
    deck = []
    for suit in suits:
        for denomination in denominations:
            ds = denomination + suit
            deck.append(ds)

    random.shuffle(deck)      
    return deck

def deal_cards(deck, players):
    hands = []

    for j in range(players):
        player_hand = []
        for i in range(2):
            cards = deck.pop(0)
            player_hand.append(cards)

        hands.append(player_hand)  
    return hands
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to swap your for loops so you iterate over all players for the first cars, then the second:

```
def deal_cards(deck, players):
    hands = [[] for player in range(players)]

    for _ in range(2):
        for hand in hands:
            hand.append(deck.pop(0))

    return hands
```

Comment: Problem here is the implementation of `player_hand`. You start the iteration, instantiate `player_hand`, then for each player you append that hand. You need a new hand for each player. A `Player` class with a `hand` attribute and `add_to_hand()` method would be clean.

Comment: Yes, I fixed it now.

Comment: Yea for all intensive purposes that works. But how do we know which player has what hand? I leave that to the OP to work out in class design. Solution answers the question.

Comment: The hands are in the same order as the players, assuming players are an ordered collection

Comment: Aren't the hands and players just parallel lists here? player `0` would correlate to the first position in `hands`?

Comment: Yes they are, you can assign each hand to each player in sequence.

Comment: @RoadRunner Yes. The point I am trying to make is we take in the players parameter, and use it as what? A count? Why not `numPlayers` vice `players`? My 0.02 on a class design for a case like this is all. Solution does solve the OP's question.

Comment: I agree with you @pstatix, OO is well suited for this application; however, we will need to wait for the OP's questions when he decides to change his design, faces difficulties, and requests help on SO.

Comment: @pstatix Cool., I was just making sure.

Comment: I think this answer needs to use `hands = [[] for _ in range(players)]` if `players` is a number, rather than a list of player names or something (as the original code suggests).